# How to make assertion of dialog.message in playwright?

Tags: python, pytest, playwright, playwright-python

In one of my tests I need to assert message in browser dialog.
I created dialog handler in test

```
page.on('dialog', BasePage.dialog_handle)
```

`page` is default playwright fixture.

The handler itself is

```
def dialog_handle(dialog):
    message = dialog.message
    dialog.dismiss()
```

Here is full example of the test with dialog on the page

```
from playwright.sync_api import Page


def dialog_handle(dialog):
    message = dialog.message
    dialog.dismiss()


def test_dialog(page):
    page.goto('https://dialog.antonzimaiev.repl.co')
    page.on('dialog', dialog_handle)
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Диалог Alert").click()
```

How can I retrieve dialog.message to assert it using pytest?

Comment: you get the content of the message? what´s hindering you to do ```expect()``` on it? Sorry I only know NodeJS. However, I guess pytest provides a similar comparison

Comment: Can you share a bit more code, like the test boilerplate and the way you're launching your Playwright instance? Are you using the sync API or the async API? A simple page that runs a dialog would also be useful to see, so I can provide full, working code that we can both agree solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I edited the question, now you can see full test with example of a page. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with some scoping readjustments:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright  # 1.37.0


def test_dialog(page):
    dialog_message = None

    def handle_dialog(dialog):
        nonlocal dialog_message

        # assert here
        print(dialog.message) # => Hello from Open Solutions 

        # or save the message in the enclosing scope...
        dialog_message = dialog.message
        dialog.dismiss()

    page.goto("https://dialog.antonzimaiev.repl.co")
    page.once("dialog", handle_dialog)
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Диалог Alert").click()

    # ... and assert here
    print(dialog_message) # => Hello from Open Solutions 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        page = browser.new_page()
        test_dialog(page)
```

There's nothing special about pytest per se here--you can drop the `test_dialog` function body right into a pytest test case and use assertions from that, or any other testing library you like.

Race conditions aren't an issue here since the dialog blocks the script after the `.click()` operation until it's dismissed.

---

This pattern can be factored to be reusable across tests or in a POM, if that's a concern. For example:

```py
def accept_dialog(page, trigger_dialog):
    dialog_message = None

    def handle_dialog(dialog):
        nonlocal dialog_message
        dialog_message = dialog.message
        dialog.dismiss()

    page.once("dialog", handle_dialog)
    trigger_dialog()
    return dialog_message


def test_dialog(page):
    page.goto("https://dialog.antonzimaiev.repl.co")
    dialog_message = accept_dialog(
        page,
        lambda: page.get_by_role("button", name="Диалог Alert").click()
    )
    print(dialog_message) # => Hello from Open Solutions
```

Comment: Looks like I need to declare function `handle_dialog` in every test. To be honest, I don't know how to implement that solution in Page Object Model. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: No problem, thanks for the clear question and minimal example. You don't need to declare it in each test necessarily--see the update. The point here is to show the general pattern to make scoping possible. Once you have that, you can refactor as necessary to fit your use case. Curious why this was downvoted. It answers the question and is helpful. I can show it being used in pytest, but it seems tangential.